# How do I rename devices when using ZFS fuse on linux

Tags: ubuntu, zfs

I've just started using ZFS on linux and have already run into problems.

I connected my old data drive to my server to copy my data to my new ZFS volume. However, when I removed this drive and rebooted Linux, I found that my devices had been renumbered and ZFS could no longer mount its pool.

> zpool status

```
  pool: media
 state: UNAVAIL
status: One or more devices could not be opened.  There are insufficient
        replicas for the pool to continue functioning.
action: Attach the missing device and online it using 'zpool online'.
   see: http://www.sun.com/msg/ZFS-8000-3C
 scrub: none requested
config:

        NAME        STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
        media       UNAVAIL      0     0     0  insufficient replicas
          raidz1-0  UNAVAIL      0     0     0  insufficient replicas
            sdc     FAULTED      0     0     0  corrupted data
            sdd     FAULTED      0     0     0  corrupted data
            sde     UNAVAIL      0     0     0  cannot open
```

The devices are now sdb,sdc,sdd. What can I do rename the devices?
I'm using Ubuntu 11.04.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that just doing a "zpool export" and "zpool import" fixed the problem.